# Network mode for docker container to connet existing container network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, containers

Good day, could you please suggest network mode for my problem below.

I have 5 micro services running on 5 docker containers on same Linux box which are communicating with
bridge network

```yaml
networks:
  bis-bridge:
    name: bis-bridge
    driver: bridge
```

Now I need to create new container which can be **installed on same Linux box** where 5 micro services are running **or another Linux box** in the same network(user option). can I use the existing 'bis-bridge' network for new container to connect to the existing network?

```yaml
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: bis-bridge
```

or network mode need to be changed to connect from **same Linux box / from another Linux box**?

Comment: Yes you can use an external (existing) network. Moreover, the second snippet should work in certain conditions. Why do you ask? Is there an error?

Comment: i am getting below error if i run container from anoter linux box. ERROR: Network bis-bridge declared as external, but could not be found. Please create the network manually using `docker network create bis-bridge` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Within one machine you can use an external network to connect a container to an existing stack. The second snippet should work if you specified no networks under the new container or explicitly used the `default` one. Like this:

```yaml
version: "3"
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: bis-bridge
services:
# both will work
  one:
    image: someimage
  
  two:
    image: someimage
    networks:
      default:
```

As for joining containers from another machine (physical or virtual), it also possible but with another network type. You need an [overlay](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/) network and it is only available in [swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) mode. Note that this is not a quick hack but a step from local deployments to an orchestration framework. You'd have to:

- Form a cluster (swarm that is) by joining nodes together.
- Modify all your service definition for swarm and re-deploy old containers. I guess you would like to keep old containers on the old node and without explicitly defining that you will have containers randomly spread between nodes of the cluster.
- Learn to use `docker service` and `docker stack` instead of `docker-compose` command.
- [Administer swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/admin_guide/).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am new to docker. If i use overlay network, is it possible to install the contains on same host or it allows only to install multiple hosts only? Why because my requirement is the new container can be onstalled on same host where 5 micro services are running or different host.

Comment: @user3928249 you'd have to modify service definitions with [placement constraints](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#placement). More specifically, you need to write on which node you want to deploy this service container(s). You can stick to node id or some node labels.

Comment: Thank you. With Weave Net is it possibe to resolve my issue?

Comment: @user3928249 I'm not familiar with it.